# Authentication for grafana behind a reverse niginx proxy

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, nginx, grafana

I am running a react app with a django backend. Users can log in to my app via django and are redirected to my react app. Now I want to show a grafana panel. I already set up a self-hosted grafana instance with a reverse proxy (for https). I can embedd the panel without a problem (iframe) when I use grafanas `anonymous_authentication`. But this is not an option for me. Also not an option for me is a login page on in app/iframe. I am reading alot that there is the option to manage the authentication via the reverse proxy. But since I am a nginx noob, I don't really know how I can implement this.

Can someone guide me here? I think I have to somehow log in via the proxy to grafana

My nginx setup thus far:

```
server {
    server_name  myserver.co;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass           http://localhost:3000/;
    }
    ##here is also some cert stuff
}
server {
    if ($host = myserver.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  myserver.co;
    return 404; 
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/jangaraj/grafana-iframe#i-want-to-have-grafana-in-my-app-as-an-iframe-and-i-would-like-to-have-seamless-login-experience

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `auth_request` from Nginx? It will allows you to make the validation before allowing/denying access to the Grafana.

```
server {
    server_name myserver.co;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }

    location /grafana/ {
        auth_request /auth;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
    }

    location = /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/auth/;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }

}

server {
    if ($host = myserver.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name myserver.co;
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will try this. Does that mean that I need another django view where I validate a token which then returns 2xx response to which my grafana server redirects?

Comment: In my opinion I would say yes

Comment: I tried this approach and I can route my request to my authentication endpoint which then gives me a 200 back. But then I get a nginx error from grafana saying `no resolver defined to resolve mydomain.de while sending to client`. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: Is your Grafana instance is running on the same host as NGINX?

Comment: @Ahmed The Grafana runs behind a reverse proxy (nginx) on the same server. But the django app wich also uses nginx (in docker) is on a different server

Comment: Maybe I am doing this wrong.... The iframe URL is supposed to have `/auth/`  in it?

Answer (score 1):

I also have grafana behind nginx and I had to add all these specific location blocks in my grafana.example.com server section:

```
        location / {
            if ($http_origin ~* (https?://[^/]*\.example\.com(:[0-9]+)?)) {  #Test if request is from allowed domain, you can use multiple if
                set $cors "true";                                               #statements to allow multiple domains, simply setting $cors to true in each one.
            }

            if ($cors = 'true') {
                add_header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;           #this mirrors back whatever domain the request came from as authorized, as
                add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";          #as long as it matches one of your if statements
                add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, OPTIONS";
                add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, origin, accept";
            }
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                #
                # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but arent
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                #
                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            }

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }

        location /api/live/ws {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
```

Comment: where are you authenticating your request?